# Trigger iOS universal link on browser redirect

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

I have universal links set up for a native app. E.g. when I tap a link to my website (say `https://my.website.com`) from an email app, the native app opens automatically. But when I browse some website, which redirects me to `https://my.website.com` in safari, all I get is a bar at the top, suggesting me to open in the native app. Moreover that bar is only visible if I drag down a bit, so it's not visible immediately. How can it be fixed? how can I make the app auto-open in such case?

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I'm hitting the same issue.